# $\int_0^x \frac{t^n}{1-t} dt = ?$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to calculate the integral, $\int_0^x \frac{t^n}{1-t} dt$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in (0;1)$ are some constants, but I do not know how to do it.

I tried the following methods:

1. Decomposition of $\frac{t^n}{1-t}$ into the sum of primitive fractions

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^x \frac{t^n}{1-t} \, dt 
&= \int_0^x \frac{(1-(1-t))^n}{1-t} \, dt \\ 
&= \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k}C_n^k \int_0^x (1-t)^{k-1} \, dt \\ 
&= \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k}C_n^k \int_{1-x}^1 t^{k-1} \, dt \\ 
&= -\ln(1-x) + \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k}C_n^k\frac{1 - (1-x)^k}{k} 
\end{align*}
$$

And here I am stuck, not knowing how to find the closed form of this sum.

2. Integration by parts

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^x \frac{t^n}{1-t} \, dt 
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^x \frac{t^{n-1}}{1-t} \, dt^2 \\ 
&= \frac{x^{n+1}}{2(1-x)} - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^x \frac{t^2 ((n-1)t^{n-2}(1-t) 
+ t^{n-1})}{(1-t)^2} \, dt \\ 
&= \frac{x^{n+1}}{2(1-x)} 
- \frac{n-1}{2} \int_0^x \frac{t^{n}}{1-t} \, dt 
- \frac{1}{2} \int_0^x \frac{t^{n+1}}{(1-t)^2} \, dt 
\end{align*}
$$

$$\int_0^x \frac{t^n}{1-t} dt = \int_{1-x}^1 (1-t)^n d \ln(t) = -x^n\ln(1-x) + n \int_{1-x}^1 (1-t)^{n-1}\ln(t)dt$$

Neither of the right parts of those equalities seems to be any easier than the initial integral.

3. WolframAlpha

> Standard computation time exceeded... Try again with Pro computation time

Comment: Add and substract 1 from the numerator of the integrand.

Comment: Use the substitution $u=1-t.$